# Looking for a localizable WPF Keyboard control for Kiosk

Tags: wpf, controls, keyboard, kiosk, on-screen-keyboard

I'm working on a project that is using WPF on an XPe box that will be deployed as a kiosk application (touchscreen only, no keyboard/mouse), and we have the need for an onscreen keyboard.  We can't use the built-in XP one because the buttons are too small to be touched, and it can't be styled.

We actually don't need to be a 'real' keyboard (sending scancodes, always on top, etc) since the values entered will be put into a single textbox in a custom dialog, and we don't want to allow them to alt-f4 out of the app, etc.

I have found plenty of controls that support an english-only keyboard or even building a customized layout, but I am coming up short on a generic control that will change layout/character set based on the InputManager CultureInfo.  It needs to support all of the OS languages (preferably out of the box without having to build a custom layout for each language we support), which seems to be the largest sticking point at the moment.

Does anyone have a control they use to accomplish something similar?  Almost everything I've found doesn't support the varying layouts and character sets out of the box, or it's some awful early 90's C++ component that can't be styled at all.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FPS Components](http://fpscomponents.com/Products/WPF/virtual-keyboard.aspx) claims:

> any language that is added to user
>   Windows settings can be automatically
>   generated on runtime. Also users can
>   add their own custom language layouts
>   by adding a new XML file into Layouts
>   folder

I've never used this product though. I am just aware of it's existence.

Comment: It looks like this component will have to do.  It supports changing the values of each key, but not necessarily the arrangement of the keys (French, for example, uses AZERTY instead of QWERTY).  We'll have to build the layouts manually for those languages.  Thanks for the reply.